# php: how to read only txt files in a directory

Tags: php

i have a folder called XXX it contains .jpg .gif .txt .... etc

i want only to read .txt files how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate over specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122693/iterate-over-specific-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) to get an array of file names that match a given pattern. Here’s the example from the manual page:

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GlobIterator`

```
$iterator = new GlobIterator('*.txt', FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME);
$n = 0;
foreach ( $iterator as $item ) {
    printf("[%d] %s\r\n", ++ $n, $iterator->key());
}
```