# How to display the file name of a notepad/text file from a local server using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have stored a notepad/text file in a Document Root. I did not save the file in the database. Please tell me how to get the file name of the file and display the files in order. Thanks

Comment: [How to read all files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950682/php-how-to-read-only-txt-files-in-a-directory) & [how to print the content of individual file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) - no point to answer, it all has been answered before. you just need to look.

Comment: Your question is not clear - if you have just one file list of one item is always ordered, and since you saved the file you'd better know its name...

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like the `file_get_contents` function?
It sounds like you want to do something like this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
If you want to display the content of the file you would then call something like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('/people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

Comment: thanks for all your examples! :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
<?php
if ($directory = opendir('/')) { // if the dir can be opened
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($directory))) {
        echo "$filename\n"; //printing file names
    }
    closedir($directory);
}
?>
```

*(from http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)*

will show unordered list of files. To show it ordered. you may put it in an array and then sort it.

But if you have a textfile that contains filenames, use `file_get_contents` (*http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php*), put it in array and then sort it, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$txtFiles = glob("*.txt")
?>

<html>
 <ul>
  <?php foreach ( $txtFiles as $fileName ) { ?>
  <li><?php echo $filename ?></li>
  <?php } ?>
 </ul>
</html>
```

Check http://php.net/glob