# Faster way to match filename in a folder containing thousend of files

Tags: php, file, pattern-matching

I was using this readdir to find a file in a folder

```
$handler = opendir($folder);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

  if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file,0,7) == '98888000') {
    print $file. "<br />";
  }

}
```

but since I have tons of files in the folder it takes some minutes to complete the request: how can I fast it up?
Consider I'm on PHP5 + IIS.

I've tried even glob()

```
foreach (glob($folder.98888000."*.pdf") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

but it returned nothing.

Comment: It shouldn't take minutes to go through even hundreds of thousands of files! Are you sure you don't have bigger issues, like exhausted inodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) maybe? It finds files matching a pattern:

```
glob('98888000*')
```

might work.

If you need `opendir` and `readdir`, then you might want to have a look at [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch).

Comment: I had a look at glob before posting. I'm updating my code with the solution tried first.

Comment: The point is that `glob` will use the OS's own matching facilities (or at least the ones natively implemented in PHP) and therefore will be much faster than taking substrings for every file name.

Answer (score 1):

First check if `$folder` contains a `/` at it's end or not, this could have caused your problem with `glob` (the pattern was just wrong). So add things as needed and remove those things not needed to write a propper glob pattern:

```
$folder = realpath($folder);
foreach (glob($folder.'/98888000*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

I used the [`GLOB_NOSORT`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for speed reasons.

Instead of using `glob()` you can make use of the [`GlobIterator` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php):

```
$folder = realpath($folder);
$query = $folder.'/98888000*';
foreach(new GlobIterator($query) as $file)
{
    $name = $file->getFilename();
    $size = $file->getSize();
    echo "$name size $size \n";
}
```

**Related:** [Iterate over specific files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122693/iterate-over-specific-files-in-a-directory) and  [9 Ways to Iterate Over a Directory in PHP](http://jdhsu.blogspot.com/2010/01/9-ways-to-iterate-over-directory-in-php.html).